# Angular ng-bind-html not sanitizing apostrophe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I'm using `ng-bind-html` to sanitize HTML in a `directive` template:

```
<h2><a href="{{ post.url }}" ng-bind-html="post.title"></a></h2>
```

The compiled output is correct, with one exception, it's not sanitizing the HTML apostrophe which is being printed as `â€tm`. The page is encoded as `charset='utf-8'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-bind-html` does a lot for your needs, but to go beyond the basic you should investigate the [$sce service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look through the documentation and see if I can find a solution.

Comment: so basically you tell him to read the doc... should be a comment not and answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if I understand your question but why don't try escaping the appostrophe with slash? Like

```
\"
```

or

```
\'
```

Comment: That won't work. `post.title` is the value of a JSONP object property.